# How do I access a model's nested one-to-many relations?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-rest-framework

I have three models as shown below:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class MenuCategory(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    menu_category = models.ForeignKey(MenuCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

A restaurant *has many* menu categories, which *has many* menu items.

Is this the right way to lay out these relationships? What's the most efficient way to get ALL the menu items for a given restaurant?

I'm hoping there's a more effective way than to loop across all menu categories for a given restaurant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain all `MenuItem`s for a given restaurant with:

```
MenuItem.objects.filter(menu_category__restaurant=my_restaurant)
```

where *`my_restaurant`* is the `Restaurant` object for which you want to retrieve the `MenuItems`.

Django will construct a query for this, and the database will perform JOINs, such that it looks like:

```
SELECT menu_item.*
FROM menu_item
JOIN menu_category
    ON menu_item.menu_category_id = menu_category.id
WHERE menu_category.restaurant_id = my_restaurant_id
```

Since `ForeignKey`s add indexes to the table, typically this JOIN is done quite fast.